# Error with prepareForSegue ""unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value""

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass data from a PFTableViewCell to the next view controller(details) with prepareForSegue function. I think I've put in the right code but when I run the app and click on the cell, my app crashes and I get this message "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I've tried many variations for the prepareForSegue function to pass the data but it would never appear on the next view controller.

In my FirstViewController I have this code written:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)  {
            if segue.identifier == "Detail" {
                if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? ResponseViewController {
                let path = tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow!
                let cell = tableView!.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path!) as! Post
                destination.name = (cell.name.text!)
                destination.message = (cell.message.text!)
              }
```

Here is the code to display the data passed in the ResponseViewController:

```
  var name = String?()
    var message = String?()

@IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userMessage: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  userName.text! = name!
  userMessage.text! = message!
}
```

Now how do I fix this issue or better yet how can I prepareForSegue in swift 2.0?

Comment: one of your variables is nil--you can't use a nil value in your expressions. If you unwrap 'nil' using '!' your program crashes with this error message. (Swift forces you to deal with `nil` values at compile time, vs at runtime as with Obj-C)

Comment: try replacing every '!' with '?', and getting your code to compile that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your Optional variables contains *nil*.

Using '!' forces unwrapping of Optional values. If an Optional contains nil when it is unwrapped your program crashes with this error message. Try to avoid using force-casting (`as!`) and force-unwrapping.

Here's a nil safe version

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)  {
            if segue.identifier == "Detail" {
                if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? ResponseViewController
                , path = tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow
                , cell = tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath( path ) as? Post
            {
                destination.name = cell.name.text ?? "nil"
                destination.message = cell.message.text ?? "nil"
            }
```

and

```
var name: String?
var message: String?

@IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var userMessage: UILabel?

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userName?.text = name ?? "nil"
    userMessage?.text = message ?? "nil"
}
```

N.b.:

- `??` is the nil-coalescing operator. If the value on the left is *nil*, the value on the right is substituted.
- You can optionally call methods on an optional value using the `?.` accessor. If the value on the left is `nil`, the result will short-circuit to `nil`

Comment: Ok my app doesn't crash anymore(Thank you for that!) but the data from the firstviewcontroller hasn't passed to the ResponseViewController. Do you know why that could and how I can do this?

Comment: Well, that was the problem: one of your values is _nil_. You have to track down why it's _nil_ instead of the value you expect. You could ask a separate question?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to coding. What do you mean by tracking down why it's nil? And if ask a separate question would be able to help me solve this issue? I've been stuck on it with my team for over a week.

Comment: Any variable whose type ends with a `?` is optional. That means it is either a value or it is no value at all. (_nil_ is the name for no value). So at some point, one of your variables of optional type was assigned _nil_. The easiest way to resolve this would be to add breakpoints to your code and then run it. Execution of your program will be paused when it reaches a line of code where you have set a breakpoint. Then, you can use the debugger to inspect what values your variables have been assigned. Sorry--any more would be beyond the scope of a simple answer.