# How can I resize a UIImage as it becomes more disorted?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, cifilter

I've got a dynamically distorted UIImage appearing in a UIImageView (basically updating the UIImageView's image with a function). Every time I try to crop the image as it grows based on the distortion and touch response, I get a fatal error - trying to unwrap an optional coming back with nil.

Any ideas?

```
    func pincushionDistortionWithAmount(amount:CGFloat, position:CGPoint){

    //1 Remove All Subviews
    for view in subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    //2
    let beginImage = CIImage(image: UIImageView.image)

    // 3
    let filter :CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIBumpDistortion")!
    filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(CIVector(x: position.x, y: position.y), forKey:"inputCenter")
    filter.setValue(75, forKey:"inputRadius")
    filter.setValue(-1.0 * amount, forKey:"inputScale")

    // 4
    let newImage:UIImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage!)
    let imageViewWidth = pinImageView.frame.size.width
    let imageViewHeight = pinImageView.frame.size.height
    let imageWidth = newImage.size.width
    let imageHeight = newImage.size.height

    if imageWidth > imageViewWidth{
        print("Image is wider than ImageView")
        //Code to crop image to fit in imageView
    }
    if imageHeight > imageViewHeight{
        print("Image is taller than ImageView")
        //Code to crop image to fit in imageView

    }
    UIImageView.image = newImage
    addSubview(UIImageView)
}
```

Comment: Can you identify what is the error line using Breakpoints?

Comment: Not throwing an error with this code, but whenever I try to crop the UIImage I get out of the filter, it throws the error when referring to it.

Comment: What does the cropping code look like? Here you have a `CIImage`-backed `UIImage`. Lots of code you find that does basic image processing online assumes that you have a `CGImage`-backed `UIImage` and thus you get a `nil` exception when they try to access `image.CGImage`. In this case, you may have to render the `CIImage` manually using something like this: `CIContext(options:nil).createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, fromRect:filter.outputImage!.extent`

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/33378974/210171